# how to extract data from multiple iframes using jsoup and write it to one xml file

Tags: iframe, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to extract data from an html page. I'm able to extract data if the page has only one iframe. But, if the page has links which would open another iframe how do i extract data from the second iframe and write all the data to one xml file. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

One approach could be to parse the parent website for iframe tags and extract the "src".
The "src"-values can be used to download each iframe content and parse it, if really necessary also to combine them.

```
    String url = "http://example.com/";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("url").get();

Elements es = document.select("iframe"); 

String[] iframesrc;
int iframeCount = es.size();
iframesrc = new String [iframeCount];
//extract iFrame sources:
int i=0;
for(Element e : es)
{
    iframesrc[i] = e.getElementsByTag("iframe").attr("src"); 
    i++;
}

//get iFrame content
Document [] iframeDoc;
iframeDoc = new Document[iframeCount];
int j = 0;
for (String s : iframesrc){
    iframeDoc[j] = Jsoup.connect("url"+iframesrc[j]).get(); //pay attention that the correct url is built at this point!!!
j++;
}

/*now you got the parent site as well as the iframe "childs" as documents. I've no experience in combining Documents. If nothing works you may try document.tostring()*/
```

To write Documents to a file i use this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class Write2File {
     public static void saveFile(Document xmlContent, String saveLocation) throws IOException {
         FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(saveLocation);
         BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
         bufferedWriter.write(xmlContent.toString());
         bufferedWriter.close();
         System.out.println("File writing completed.");
     }
}
```